# Почему при записи в файл все печатается в одну строчку? Как поправить?

Tags: java

Почему при записи в файл все печатается в одну строчку? Как поправить?

```
writeFile.append(String.valueOf((int)(it + ut - 1)));
writeFile.append("\n");
```

Comment: На какой ОС вы открываете файл?

Comment: ... и каким редактором?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забегая вперед: `\n` это дефолтный перенос строки в unix, на винде обычно `\r\n`.